# What does the => sign mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, operators

For some reason I can't find the answer to this anywhere. I tried Googling "Haskell equal sign arrow" and I'm not getting any results. Let's say we have the following function:

```
sendMessage :: MonadM e m => Message -> m ()
sendMessage message = do
    mClient  <- getMessageClient
    liftIO $ send mClient message
```

Where exactly are e and m getting used? Are they being passed into the Message object (function?) and then outputted as a single type, m ()?

I don't think it helps that I'm very new to Haskell, but any help is appreciated here.

Comment: It is type context: https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: @LeeDuhem Can you briefly explain what that means in simple terms? As someone who doesn't program in Haskell I'm having trouble understanding the link you sent.

Comment: This must be a duplicate, but I don't know how to find an older copy.

Comment: If you come from Java, a type class is a bit like an interface.

Comment: Looks like your question has already been answered :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First off: if you want to know what such and such operator does, don't ask StackOverflow, ask [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3D%3E)!

But in fact Hayoo is no use for `=>` in particular because, unlike almost everything else in Haskell, this is built-in syntax and not an operator that's defined in some library.

Your signature

```
sendMessage :: MonadM e m => Message -> m ()
```

means the following: the type of `sendMessage` is `Message -> m ()`, where `m` can be any monad that has an instance of the `MonadM` type class.

That probably doesn't help you much, because in fact `MonadM` is a rather involved type class. Better consider a simpler example:

```
sum :: Num n => [n] -> n
```

This means: the type of sum is `[n] -> n`, where `n` can be any number type that's an instance of the [`Num`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num) class, i.e. the class of types supporting subtraction, multiplication, obviously *addition* etc.. Actually the syntax is shorthand for

```
sum :: ∀ n . Num n => [n] -> n
```

meaning that *for all* types `n` which fulfill the constraint `Num n`, the function `sum` has the signature `[n] -> n`.

You can *instantiate* such a polymorphic function with any concrete number type: e.g.

```
sum :: [Int] -> Int
```

In your example you'd probably instantiate it to something like

```
sendMessage :: Message -> MessageT IO ()
```

Comment: Thanks for the Hayoo reference; I'll totally be using that a ton. So, if I understand this correctly, anything before the => sign is just a type restriction to the matching input/output elements?

Comment: Basically yes. In fact it's often useful to disregard the constraints at first, and either consider an example instantiation or the unconstrained polymorphic function to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: [hoogle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hoogle) instead of [hayoo](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Hayoo), as the latter has no upload since 2012, and the link above is not reachable, either.

Comment: @RolandPuntaier yes, thanks. Please don't hesitate to make such remarks directly as _edits_ in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The type signature

```
sendMessage :: MonadM e m => Message -> m ()
```

can be read

> Assuming that the constraint `MonadM e m` holds, `sendMessage` has type `Message -> m ()`

`MonadM` is (almost certainly) a multi-parameter type class with a functional dependency. Its definition probably looks vaguely like

```
class Monad m => MonadM e m | m -> e where ....
```

You don't have to worry about that right now. Writing such classes is a somewhat advanced topic. But it expresses that some operations are available that relate the types `e` and `m`, where the type `e` is determined by the type `m`.

Comment: So are e & m still inputs to this function? Or is it just Message? Or...both?

Comment: The input to this function is just a `Message`. The output is of any `m` type you choose, *so long as* `m` is an instance of the typeclass `MonadM e m`.

Comment: @Niko: they are _type-level arguments_ of the function, if you will. But it's not necessarily helpful to look at it this way.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. My only question is how can you verify that m is of type MonadM e m if you don't know what e is? Or am I misinterpreting what "e" is

Comment: @Niko, you shouldn't need to worry about `e` here, because it seems to be irrelevant to `sendMessage`, though it's presumably important for some other operations. `e` will be fixed by whatever instance `m` has. You'll have to check the documentation or GHC to see if your particular `m` has an instance. Note also that `m` *is* a type, and does not have *type* `MonadM e m`, but rather *satisfies the constraint* `MonadM e m`.

Comment: @dfeuer That clears it up. Thanks for your patience.