# What's the difference between =, <- ,<= In haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax

We usually see `=`, `<-`, `<=` in haskell. What's the difference between these?

Comment: Partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624408/equal-vs-left-arrow-symbols-in-haskell

Answer (score 12):

- `=` means **defined to be equal**. I.e., if I write

  ```
  x = 5
  ```

  somewhere in a file, I can then at any other point (within the same scope) replace `5` with `x` and vice versa – they're the same thing. (And will always remain the same.) The definition can however also refer back to the name you're binding it to, to give recursive computations like

  ```
  fibonacci :: [Integer]
  fibonacci = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibonacci)
  ```

  In this case, you could still at any point replace `fibonacci` with `0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibonacci)`, though of course you would need to repeat the process infinitely.
  A `=` definition can stand either at the top-level, i.e. in a line of its own in the module, or within a `let` or `where` block:

  ```
  silly :: Integer -> Integer
  silly x = y
   where y = let z = x + 1
             in z - 1
  ```

  Here, `silly` is a top-level binding (with a function argument), `y` is a `where` binding, and `z` is a `let` binding.
- `<-` means essentially **defined as the *result* of**, meaning the result of a monadic computation. It usually stands in a `do` block, for instance:

  ```
  main :: IO ()
  main = do
     putStrLn "Enter your name, please"
     userName <- getLine
     putStrLn $ "Hello, " ++ userName
  ```

  Note that this is very different from

  ```
  main = do
     putStrLn "Enter your name, please"
     let userName' = getLine
     putStrLn $ "Hello, " ++ userName'  -- error here
  ```

  What this would do is not define `userName` as the string entered by the user, but as *the action that requests a string to be entered*. `userName` is a `String`, but `userName' :: IO String`.

  `<-` is also used in list comprehensions:

  ```
  squareNums :: [Integer]
  squareNums = [x^2 | x <- [0..]]
  ```

  It may seem that this does something different from `userName <- getLine`, but actually it does the same thing, just in a different monad (list instead of IO). In fact I could also write that as

  ```
  squareNums = do
      x <- [0..]
      return $ x^2
  ```

  There's also a third use of `<-` which is really different: [pattern guards](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard), but these are not so common.
- `<=` is just a library function (in infix-operator form). This is also the case for most other symbolic “syntax” you'll encounter in Haskell. You can [ask Hayoo](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%3C%3D) about such operators, it will tell you that `<=` is [defined in the `Data.Ord` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:-60--61-) and is simply the less-that-or-equal comparison operator.

   You can also define such operators yourself – if it weren't already in the standard library, I could easily define

  ```
  (<=) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
  x <= y = not $ x > y
  ```

  Incidentally, that `=>` in the signature is something completely different – this is again built-in syntax. There was also a [question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084551/what-does-the-sign-mean-in-haskell) this week.

Answer (score 5):

`=` is a binding. It binds a name to a value/expression. You use it for top-level bindings, in let blocks and in where blocks.

```
myfun x = let y = x + 1
          in z y
  where z n = n * n
```

`<-` is a monadic extraction. It's part of the `do` notation and introduces a name bound to the contents of a monad.

```
main = do
  name <- getLine
  putStrLn ("Hello, " ++ name)
```

`<=` is the less-or-equal operator defined in the `Cmp` typeclass.

```
message x = if x < 18 then "No, you can't vote." else "Go ahead."
```

Comment: It's very clear! Thanks a lot! May I ask what is a 'top-level binding'? What's the difference between a top-level binding and other bindings?

Comment: Top-level bindings are those directly at file level (or in a module's where block). The only real difference to other bindings is their visibility.

Comment: I think *"monadic extraction"* should really be *"monadic binding"*.